# Can't put the menu in the middle

Tags: wordpress, templates, menu, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

It is a WordPress site and Enfold template. How can I make the menu transparent and center it?

In the template settings, there is an option to make the header transparent, but there is no option to make the menu transparent

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a transparent and centered menu in your Enfold template, you can leverage custom CSS.

First, set the header to transparent using the template settings. Then, inspect the menu element and use CSS to adjust its background color to transparent.

To center it, you can use flexbox or text-align properties depending on your layout. Remember, CSS is your creative canvas – experiment, adjust, and refine until you achieve the precise look you envision.